# Wifi hard-locked on Ubuntu 16.04 (DELL M4800)

Tags: 16.04, wireless

despite it worked perfectly until 48 hours ago, the wifi is now hard-locked on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop (a DELL M4800).
From the Settings Menu, I removed the airplane mode, which was on (weird) and I tried to switch the wifi on, but it does not work. 
Then, I went on the terminal. I tried `rfkill list` and this it tells me that the wifi is Hard-Locked. Even if I use `rfkill unblock wifi` nothing changes. I also entered the BIOS and everything is normal there.

Do you have any suggestion to unlock my wifi?

Best,

Jacopo Cerri

Comment: What is the position of the wireless switch; #15 here: https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_precision_mobile/precision-m4800-workstation_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf

Comment: It was turned off! That was an amazingly embarrassing moment to me! Fixed.

Comment: Glad it’s working by whatever means.